# put value of hidden input into variable using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup that I need to put the value of the input named "ProductCode" to a variable named lets say product_id using jquery

It's probably easy but for some reason I simply can't figure it out.

```
<input type="image" src="/v/vspfiles/templates/100/images/buttons/btn_addtocart.gif" id="btnaddtocart" name="btnaddtocart" alt="Add to cart" border="0" onclick="return addToCart2(this.form, this);" />

                          <input type="hidden" name="ReplaceCartID" value="" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="ProductCode" value="M406789" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="e" value="" />

                              <input type="hidden" name="ReturnTo" value="ShoppingCart.asp" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.val()` method.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/uzWJs/

```
var theValue = $('input[name=ProductCode]').val();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/val/

For example:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    var theValue = $('input[name=ProductCode]', this).val();
    alert( theValue );
});
```

Comment: LOL, thx this is what I had before var product_id = $("input[name$='ProductCode']");
I almost had it just forgot the .val() and remove the quotes

Comment: was going to but it said it had to wait 10 minutes, thx again

Answer (score 2):

Thats quite simple, just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var product_id = $("input[name='ProductCode']").val();
    alert(product_id):  //this is the result
});
```